# ListView within a ListView, can't track ID of nested lv in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

it might probably seem weird, or I probably failed to notice my error somewhere, but writing in code behind, I could not see the ID of the second ListView.

**Using ASP.NET WebForms WebSite**

Here is my .aspx code

```
            <div class="slideshow">
                <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvCarousel" OnItemDataBound="lvCarousel_ItemDataBound" DataKeyNames="brand_id">
                    <LayoutTemplate>

                        <ul class="popup-slide">
                            <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></li>
                        </ul>

                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li class="popup-slideshow content-scroll ">
                            <figure class="ipad-scroll">
                                <figcaption>
                                    <div class="popup-slider">
                                        <div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                           <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                        <li data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>

                                            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvCarouselPic" OnItemDataBound="lvCarouselPic_ItemDataBound" DataKeyNames="brand_id">
                                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                <div class="item active">
                                                    <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></li>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                                    </LayoutTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgSlideShow" ImageUrl="#" />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:ListView>
                                                </ol>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>

                <nav class="popup-navigation"><span class="icon nav-prev"></span><span class="icon nav-next"></span><span class="icon nav-close"></span></nav>
            </div>
```

And here is my C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DisplayCarousel();
        }
    }
    protected void DisplayCarousel()
    {
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            List<Brand> brand = db.Brands.ToList();
            lvCarousel.DataSource = brand.OrderByDescending(b => b.date_created);
            lvCarousel.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime I try to type in the `lvCarouselPic` in C# it doesn't appear.
My problem also is that One Brand can have many pics, and here inside this slide show I want to display all the pics corresponding to each brand with the `carousel-indicators`. If you've ever worked on anything like this and could help it would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each item after its bound and do a `FindControl("id")` and cast to a `ListView` object. Then you can bind the data source.

Here is some sample code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DisplayCarousel();
    }
}
protected void DisplayCarousel()
{
    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        // get all your data first
        var DataList = db.Brands
            .Select(a => new
            {
                objBrand = a,
                PicList = a.Pics.ToList()
            })
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.objBrand.date_created)
            .ToList();


        // now bind the main listview to the Brand objects in the DataList
        lvCarousel.DataSource = Brands.Select(a => a.objBrand);
        lvCarousel.DataBind();

        foreach (ListViewItem objItem in lvCarousel.Items)
        {
            // get the data object
            var objData = DataList[objItem.DataItemIndex];

            // find the nested list view
            ListView lvCarouselPic = (ListView)objItem.FindControl("lvCarouselPic");

            // bind the data pics data source
            lvCarouselPic.DataSource = objData.PicList;
            lvCarouselPic.DataBind();

            // loop each pic item
            foreach (ListViewItem objNestedItem in lvCarouselPic.Items)
            {
                // get the pic object
                var objBrandPic = objData.PicList[objNestedItem.DataItemIndex];

                // do whatever you need with the pic data, find controls in the nested listview, etc.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now there are a few things about this code. First is I would make the AnonymousType (the var) a custom object. Then I would move my database call to an external class and make calls to that class and return the data.

I'm sure you can do the nested data binding in an OnItemCreated, however I never do.

Also, you can bind the data from the objects on the front end html (I didn't see any in your sample code). For example:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgSlideShow" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("FieldFromDatabase") %>' />
```

Hope that gets you in the right direction.

Comment: How can I bind each picture to its respective brand? With this loop I can bind the table brands to lvCarouselPic, correct? But shouldn't  I then be able to use `lvCarouselPic` in `lvCarouselPic_ItemDataBound` ?

Comment: I edited the source code to maybe give you a better idea.